# Find domain controller Mac OSX

Tags: macos, dns, controller, ldap

Is there a way to find a domain controller programatically in C++ on Mac OSX >= 10.6?

Can this be done using libldap API?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you try DNS. We found some examples for [Using DNS](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Verify%20DNS%20Records)

Comment: Is there a way to do nslookup -type=any _ldap._tcp programatically?

Comment: Sure, which program are you using?

Comment: using C++ on Mac OSX so I can use the Mac OSX frameworks also. any idea?

Comment: Not that I am aware. But you could use nslookup -type=any _ldap._tcp|grep '_ldap._tcp' |awk -F" " '{print $7}'  which will return the name of each domain controller and feed those into dscl.